# Column selection and further plotting of filtered data from datatable (DT) in Shiny

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I have two questions about datatable (DT) in Shiny and
till this moment i could not find an any answer.

I would like to select column instead of a row in datatable --> 
I have tried (as it was written on official website  http://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html):

```
datatable(..., selection = list(target = 'column'))
```

in my code::

```
datatable(data[, c("Datum", "Kunde", "Block.Nr.", "Toleranz", 
                        "Kaliberschema")], class = 'cell-border stripe', 
               rownames=FALSE, filter="top", selection = list(target = 'column'), options = list(lengthChange = FALSE, columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = "_all"), list(bSortable = FALSE, targets = "_all"))), callback=JS("
           //hide column filters for two columns
            $.each([0, 1], function(i, v) {
            $('input.form-control').eq(v).hide()});", 
            "var tips = ['Datum von..bis', 'Kunde', 'Block.Nr.',
            'Toleranz +', 'Kaliberschema'],
            header = table.columns().header();
            for (var i = 0; i < tips.length; i++) {
            $(header[i]).attr('title', tips[i]);}")) %>%
        formatStyle("Datum",  color = 'red', backgroundColor = 'lightyellow', fontWeight = 'bold')})
```

This code was not working at all, just got an error:

```
Error in match.arg(selection) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

Than i have tried inside an options smthg like this:

```
options = list(target = 'column', lengthChange = FALSE, columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = "_all")...
```

It was as well not working...

Does anyone have any ideas??

2nd Thing is that i would lke to use this selected column to plot a line plot and histogram using ggplot.

Thanks in advance for any ideas

Comment: There are a lot of things going on at your `datatable`. Without a reproducible example is difficult to pin point the problem. Have you tried commenting the `options` and `formatStyle`? Did selecting columns still not work when those parts were commented? About the 2nd question, you can use `input$tableId_columns_selected`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest development version of DT available from github or the 2015 v0.1 package release from CRAN? Your error indicates the latter; the selection options you have chosen might simply not be available. For installation from github, you may install the devtools package from CRAN and proceed via `library(devtools);install_github("rstudio/DT")`. Or even better: ask the authors when the package becomes available via CRAN, as this sort of confusion has come up elsewhere ...